# Diffusion of two particles in a Dirac Field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

I was solving a two-body diffusion problem in QFT. Considering a fermionic field, that satisfies the Dirac field, with an interaction like:

$$V(\psi,\bar{\psi}) = \frac{\lambda}{2}\left( \bar{\psi} \psi\right)^2$$

I need to compute the cross section of this system, when the particles of mass $m$ have spin $s_i$.

I tried to compute it at first order, since it has no loops and no renormalization is needed, but I am getting stuck in computing the diagrams that are needed in the process.

Can anyone give some help?

**Informations:

The cross section is given by:
$$
\sigma = \frac{1}{128\pi^2 s}\int d \Omega\left|\mathcal{M}_{fi}\right|^2
$$

**** UPDATE ****

Meanwhile I was able to compute it in first order, only for high energies (I discarded the m^2 terms in the trace expansion) where the differential cross section gave:

$$
\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}=\frac{\lambda^2 E^2}{128\pi^2}\left(3+\cos^2\theta\right)
$$

And the total cross section gives:

$$
\sigma(E)=\frac{5}{8\pi}\lambda^2E^2
$$

Comment: Your potential $\psi \bar \psi$ cannot be correct.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. It was a mistake in the exam sheet. Should be $\bar{\psi}\psi$. I'm gonna edit